# IIS Rewrite rule with QueryString in Rewrite

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having a problem with an IIS rewrite rule. We have many set up and working in our web.config file. I am trying to modify one of them. Apologies for the level of this question. I'm not experienced in this topic.

The current rule is:

```
<rule name="my-rule-test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^my-page.asp" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/my-domain/my-actual-page.asp" />
</rule>
```

This rule works fine. I'm now trying to simply add a QueryString to the Rewrite page as follows:

```
<rule name="my-rule-test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^my-page.asp" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/my-domain/my-actual-page.asp?aS=h" />
</rule>
```

This rule fails and trips the server over to the page we have set up in web.config here:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="c:\test.html" mode="On">
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Can somebody please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is not correct:Please refer to this.

```
<rules>
      <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)/$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
      </rule>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for posting. I'm not sure I understand your example and how it relates to mine. I'm not looking to create a redirect, rather a re-write on a single file, with the resultant location carrying a hard-coded QueryString parameter.